# Swift custom IntentHandler doesn't load when multiple INImage's are set

Tags: swift, widgetkit

I have a custom IntentHandler to provide a dynamic list of options for my widget to choose from. I want to add a image to it using the .displayImage and when i do so with a handful of options it works but when i do this with my whole list (approximately 70 items) the options don't load anymore on the device. Below is my code.

```
func provideSelectedProjectsOptionsCollection(for intent: SpecificWidgetIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<SelectableProject> {
    let image = INImage(named: "AvengersIcon")
    
    var projects = await ProjectService.getAll(populate: .populateNone)
        .compactMap {
            let proj = SelectableProject(identifier: "mcu-\($0.id)", display: "\($0.attributes.title)", subtitle: "MCU", image: nil)
            proj.sortKey = "MCU-\($0.attributes.title)"
            return proj
        }
    
    projects += await ProjectService.getAllOther(populate: .populateNone)
        .compactMap {
            let proj = SelectableProject(identifier: "other-\($0.id)", display: "\($0.attributes.title)", subtitle: "Related to MCU", image: nil)
            proj.sortKey = "Other-\($0.attributes.title)"
            return proj
        }
    
    projects.forEach { $0.displayImage = image }
    projects = projects.sorted(by: { $0.sortKey ?? "" < $1.sortKey ?? "" })
    return INObjectCollection(items: projects)
}
```

I also added an example with the warning (it is in dutch but the translation is: Not possible to load)
[image: IMG-0501.png]

I tried adding images to only a few items and that worked but with the whole list it didn't work.

I also tried using an image from an url and use image data but both of those options have the same result (works for a few but doesn't for the whole list)

I expect to see all images when i add the images to all my options. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?